# Report Title Will Not Stay Centered in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I've created a report with a row grouping and a column column for a report - and I have centered the report title in the report header above the tablix as shown below.  The Channel data uses an expression that replaces NULL values with a 0.

[image: Report Layout]

[image: Groupings]

The number of channels that will be displayed depends on how many channels were used during the date range provided.

For example, one particular date range will show:

[image: One Day]

But if I expand the date range and the report returns multiple channels, the report title is no longer centered:

[image: Multiple Days and Channels]

Is there a way to ensure the report title (and the expression in the footer) stays centered as the report grows depending upon the number of channels?

Additional Information Added:
Report Width is 4.6 inches, the logo box is set to 1.5 inches wide and the text box with the report title text box is set to 3.1 inches wide. Both rectangles are set to 1 inch in height.

And the alignment for the report title was already set to Horizontal: Center and Vertical: Middle.  The issue seems to be that the report will always stay centered in the 3.1 inch wide text box - but will not re-center if the text box grows due to additional columns:

[image: Alignment]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for alignment :

**1. First you have to take full size of your Expression TextBox from Logo and change the alignment of it check below snaps for that :**

[image]

**2. Right Click on your expression and select TextBox Properties :**

[image]

**3. Select Alignment option and Change Horizontal:Center and Vertical: Middle :-**

[image]

**Now your title will be in Center !!**

Comment: Thanks - I'll try this solution as soon as I am able to.

Comment: Hello Laxman - unfortunately this was already part of my solution and does not resolve as additional columns are added to the report and the width increases.

Comment: Not sure - I created a new reported and made sure I followed your steps and it still is not centered.

Comment: I am also seeing this on 1 report, but the others do not do it. This is a report with row and column grouping, but I don't think this is the problem. When I open the excel in Page Layout view, the heading text is in the left box. There are three boxes in the header, left, middle and right boxes. The justification seems to be which box the text is in. For some reason, for this report, it always puts it in the left one. I can cut and paste to the center one in the xlsx file to center it, but who wants to do that after every export? I have made sure the textbox is the whole width, etc.